# EFA with heterogeneously transformed variables

Tags: data-transformation, factor-analysis, skewness

Can I perform an EFA (oblique rotation) with variables that have undergone different types of transformations? Can I still interpret the factor loadings  and other output coherently?

For questionnaire development I want to perform an EFA with 24 variables (5 point likert scale), of which 15 have significant negative and 2 positiv skew (probability of the z score of skewness <.01; although all skewness <|1|).
Different transformations help best for different variables (log10, square root, inverse). Thus, my question (see above). Or do you have other recommendations?
Thank you!

Comment: I kind of found an answer in two previous posts on [heteroneneous transformations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34761/do-data-transformations-before-factor-analysis-need-to-be-consistent-across-diff) and on [nonnormal data in principal axis factoring](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34753/are-data-transformations-on-non-normal-data-necessary-for-an-exploratory-factor).