# PCA in the case when all directions have equal variance

Tags: pca

In the case where I have an orthogonal $m \times n$ matrix $X$, and the covariance matrix of $X$, let's call it $C$, is such that $C_{ii} = 1$ for all $i$ such that $1 \le i \le n$ and $C_{ij}=0$ otherwise, how would I pick the direction of maximal variance for PCA, given that each direction has equal variance? Could I just pick any direction in my matrix $X$?

Comment: What are about off-diagonal elements of `C`? Are they all 0? all equal? different?

Comment: PCA "hunts" after maximal variance directions within _overall_ variance: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22571/3277. It doesn't matter in this respect whether `Cii` are all equal or not.

Comment: Off-diagonal elements of $C$ would all be 0. I did see that question - my understanding from that was each principal component explains an equal part of the variance in this case; is this correct?

Comment: `Off-diagonal elements of C would all be 0` OK, then your data is spherical; go to read here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/92791/3277

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It becomes arbitrary because you can't rank the eigenvalues: they are all equal. It becomes obvious thinking about the eigendecomposition formulation instead of SVD.

PCA in this scenario makes no sense though: the variables are already principal components. If you apply PCA on this data the PCs will correspond to the original variables, with possible changes in sign introduced by the method.