# Why does adding a mean datapoint decrease the Pearson correlation coefficient $R$?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, linear

We know that for a sample (assume it's a data set that has two variables $x$ and $y$ of size $n$),
$$R = \frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{x_i-\overline{x}}{s_x}\right)\left(\frac{y_i-\overline{y}}{s_y}\right)$$

Say we add in a data point $(\overline{x}, \overline{y})$ to the sample, which lies on the linear regression trendline of the sample (?).

We can mathematically see this actually decreases the $R$ value (the sum portion for this data point is $0$, but $n$ increases by $1$ so the denominator increases). However,  cannot intuitively understand why.

Is there an intuitive explanation for this?

Thanks!

Comment: My answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/612056/247274) might be helpful, even if this is not quite a duplicate. (My hope is that you will be able to read that answer and then figure out enough to be able to post a self-answer!)

Comment: I don't "mathematically see" this at all, because including that point *shrinks* both $s_x$ and $s_y,$ which could more than compensate for the change in $n.$  In fact, this *exactly* compensates for the change.  (I understand you really mean to ask about $|R|$ rather than $R$ itself, for otherwise the claim--if it were true for positive $R$--could easily be disproven by choosing very negative $R.$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R$ is the ordinary least squares (OLS) estimate of the slope of the regression of the $y_i$ on the $x_i.$  Because the regression line must go through the point of averages $(\bar x, \bar y),$ adjoining any number of instances of that point to the dataset will not change the sum of squares and therefore will not change the OLS solution, **whence $R$ will be unchanged.**