How to show covariance doesn't capture nonlinear relationships?
I have heard that Pearson correlation is used for assessing linear relationships as well as covariance. So I was interested in determining why that was.
Let's suppose we have random variables $X$ and want to compute
$$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}\left[ (X-\bar{X})(Y-\bar{Y}) \right]$$
Then suppose we can write $Y$ in terms of $X$.
$$Y= g(X) = f(X) + h(X)$$
where $f$ is the linear portion and $h$ is nonlinear.
$$
Y = g(X) = aX + b + h(X) 
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[g(X)] & = \mathbb{E}[aX + b + h(X)]\\
&= a \mathbb{E}[X] + b + \mathbb{E}[h(X)] \\
\end{align*}
So recall we have $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}\left[ (X-\bar{X})(Y-\bar{Y}) \right]$, so then we need to simplify $Y-\bar{Y}$.
\begin{align*}
Y-\bar{Y} &= g(X) - \mathbb{E}[g(X)] \\ 
&= (aX + b + h(X)) - (a\mathbb{E}[X] + b \mathbb{E}[h(X)]) \\ 
&= a(X - \mathbb{E}[X]) + (h(X) - \mathbb{E}[h(X)]) \\ 
\end{align*}
Having found this, we can now simplify the original $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$.
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) &= \mathbb{E}[(X-\bar{X})(Y-\bar{Y})] \\ 
&= \mathbb{E}[(X-\bar{X}) (g(X) - \mathbb{E}[g(X)])] \\ 
&= \mathbb{E}[(X-\bar{X}) (a(X-\mathbb{E}[X]) + (h(X) - \mathbb{E}[h(X)]))]\\ 
&= \mathbb{E}[(X-\bar{X}) (a(X-\mathbb{E}[X])] + \mathbb{E}[(X-\bar{X})(h(X) - \mathbb{E}[h(X)]))]\\ 
&= a\operatorname{Var}(X) + \operatorname{Cov}(X,h(X))\\ 
\end{align*}
So now the question is what is $\operatorname{Cov}(X,h(X))$?
So I guess my question is, if covariance is a measure of linear relationships, does that mean $\operatorname{Cov}(X,h(X)) = 0$?
If so, how do I show that this is guaranteed to be 0 if $h$ is truly nonlinear?

A power function such as $y = ax^b$ seems to qualify as truly nonlinear but its covariance (and more importantly the corresponding correlation) is typically a long way from zero. See for example Harold Jeffreys Theory of Probability and I.J. Good https://www.jstor.org/stable/2528645

Unlike Pearson correlation, covariance itself is not a measure of the magnitude of linear relationship. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/229703/3277

Your decomposition is not defined, because "linear portion" isn't defined, either.  But if you take that to mean "the ordinary least squares regression of $Y$ on $X,$" then your question is (easily) answerable.
