# What are the assumptions of Multiple Correspondence Analysis?

Tags: categorical-data, pca, factor-analysis, correspondence-analysis

Is it possible to make Multiple Correspondence Analysis (MCA) with nominal data (such as country or gender) ? And more broadly, what are the assumptions of MCA?

For me, MCA is a type of factor analysis (FA) that allows to use nominal or ordinal data. But in this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43304/what-are-the-assumptions-of-factor-analysis) it is said that the first assumption of factor analysis is to have scale (interval or ratio) input variables. How MCA can be a type of factor analysis (that requires scale input variables) but also allow nominal or ordinal data ?

Comment: Rather than saying "it's a type of factor analysis" it would be better to say something like "it is like factor analysis in some sense, but allowing for nominal/ordinal data".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, MCA is specifically useful for nominal and ordinal level data. According to [this article](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jar/2013/302163/), there are no underlying distributional assumptions.