# In linear regression, if the random error is N(0,$\sigma^2$) does this mean Y~N($\alpha + \beta X$, $\sigma^2$)

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, gaussian-process

In linear regression, if the random error is normally distributed, does this mean the response is normal as well? In particular if $\epsilon$ ~ N(0,$\sigma^2$) does this mean Y~N($\alpha + \beta  X$, $\sigma^2$). More specifically, I am asking if Y will have a normal distribution. I know the mean will be $\alpha + \beta X$ and variance will be $\sigma^2$ but can the distribution be assumed to be normal just because $\epsilon$ is normal? Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does the misconception that Y must be normally distributed come from?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/342759/where-does-the-misconception-that-y-must-be-normally-distributed-come-from)

Comment: @Ben that link there seems more like "what are all these different sets of assumptions?" while this question seems like "why are affine transformations of normal rvs still normal?"

Comment: @s5s you can show this with moment generating functions. Have you tried that?

Comment: It's important to distinguish between the conditional distribution of Y given the value of X and the marginal distribution of Y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is pointed out in [this related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/342759/), the normality of the error term in a linear regression is not sufficient to ensure the marginal normality of the response variable.  The latter is also affected by the distribution of the explanatory variable, which is not assumed to be normal in a regression analysis.

Under the linear regression model you have specified, the *conditional* distribution of $Y$ is:

$$Y|x \sim \text{N}(\alpha + \beta x, \sigma^2).$$

The marginal distribution of $Y$ is:

$$F_Y(y) \equiv \mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant y) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi \Big( \frac{y - \alpha - \beta x}{\sigma} \Big) f_X(x) dx,$$

where $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution.  In the special case where $X \sim \text{N}$ this leads to a normal distribution, but in the more general case where the explanatory variable has some other distribution, you will often get a marginal distribution for the response variable that is not normal.

Comment: The problem with your answer about the conditional distribution of $Y$ is that you are assuming that the error terms have conditionally normal distributions, but this is not the usual implication.  The marginal distribution of the errors is what is used to check normality of the conditional $Y$ distributions.  And marginal normality of $\epsilon$ certainly *does not* imply conditional normality of the $Y$ distributions; see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/486951/102879

Comment: All regression results are conditional on $x$, so it *is* usual to assume conditional normality for the errors.

Comment: But that is not how the diagnostic procedure is used - it is based on the aggregate residuals, not on the residuals within each level of $X$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.  The residuals are functions of both the response and the explanatory variables, so they already account for variation in the latter.  The usual diagnostic is to plot the studentised residuals against the predicted values.

Comment: That plot somewhat conditions on the $x$ data, but not completely with multiple regression. But that plot is not usually intended to diagnose normality. Rather, the residual histogram and *q-q* plots are the specific diagnostic tools for the regression normality assumption. These tools clearly investigate the marginal distribution of the residuals. And as the example in stats.stackexchange.com/a/486951/102879  shows, such diagnostics can show normality (and correspond to theoretical normality) when the conditional $Y$ distributions are non-normal (and even homoscedastic).

Comment: Thanks for the link --- I see what you're talking about now.  While that is an interesting phenomenon, it does not show any deficiency in the present answer, which merely makes the usual regression assumptions (including conditional independence of the errors).  (Also, it is worth noting that you can still detect the phenomenon shown in your link using standard diagnostic plots.)

Comment: Do you mean "independence of the errors and X" rather than "conditional independence of the errors?" The latter is irrelevant here, but the former is relevant.  In any event, the conditions given by the OP do not state anything about independence of $\epsilon$ and $X$, so your conclusion "Under the linear regression model you have specified, the conditional distribution of Y is ..." is false. You might consider an edit.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is a most definitive "no."  Marginal normality of $\epsilon$ does not imply that the conditional distributions of $Y$ are normal.  See here for a counterexample:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/486951/102879

Answer (score 1):

The distribution at a fixed value of x is normal.  Y is not normal.  Just look at the histogram of the response.  It will not look like a normal distribution.  But if you look at the distribution at a fixed x, then it will look normal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if $\varepsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ $Y=\alpha+\beta x+ \epsilon$  then we can say that $Y \sim N(\alpha+\beta x,\sigma^2)$. This follows from the result that if a random variable $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then $X+a \sim N(\mu+a, \sigma^2)$, for example if $X\sim N(0, 3^2)$ then $X+2 \sim N(2, 3^2)$

Comment: The fact that if a random variable $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $X+a∼N(\mu+a,\sigma^2)$ can be established using the method of moment generating functions.

Comment: What is missing here is an implicit assumption that $\epsilon$ is normally distributed *conditional on X*.  But the usual diagnostics are done unconditionally, so this is not a relevant assumption. And further, unconditional normality of the $\epsilon$ does not imply conditional normality of $Y$.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/486951/102879